# Is it possible to make synchronous network call on ui thread in wpf (windows phone)

Tags: silverlight, networking, httpwebrequest, windows-phone-8, webclient

Is it possible to make a synchronous network call on UI thread in WPF (Windows Phone 8).
(I know it's cons, but still i need this functionality to make it work with some ported code)
Tried using [autoresetevent](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/adding-synchronous-methods) method. Due to deadlock, it is blocking ui thread and app hangs forever.

Even tried with webclient. still the UI thread is getting blocked and app hangs forever.

Any help...

Comment: The idea of a synchronous call is that it will use the resources of your UI thread which will block your UI. If you don't want the UI to be blocked you should use an asynchronous call.

Comment: Windows Phone doesn't use WPF (it is based on Silverlight 4).

Comment: sry, its just not getting blocked. The app hangs forever.

Comment: Sometime you just need to block UI thread, for example in case when you're handling application deactivation. You need to wait until all cleanup work is done, and need to do it synchronously, since otherwise app will quit before you're ready.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad idea - I've found that doing this by accident will actually lead to a complete deadlock of your UI. You need to use an asynchronous method.

Comment: yeah i know its bad. but i need to acheive this functionalty. i dont have any other option in my case

Comment: ...and this answer and your experience is showing that you don't have an option to use a synchronous network API as your app hangs forever.

Comment: fyi, I have the same requirement for windows 8, used httpclient which solved the issue. but same code is not working on windows phone 8. ([httpClient](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx) is available for windows phone)

            var hc = new HttpClient();
            var task = hc.GetStringAsync(urlpath);
            var response = task.Result;

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks from asynchronous network operations are queued on the UI thread. If you block the thread to wait for it, the callback will never arrive because it is waiting for access to the same thread.

You do have another option though... If you have ported the code, then you will have to change it to support async operations.

Comment: If I'm using code like this: `var client = new HttpClient(); var task = client.GetAsync("just some address SO doesn't mangle"); var data = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);" then the callback is **not** running on UI thread anymore, but there are still issues with the deadlocks (I have a bit different issues, but I think they're related).