# Blocking asynchronous operation in Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, windows-phone-8

I am trying send the http post from the windows phone to the server and I am getting some of problem via sending the post data.I put the break point in button_click_1 function and I found that it would not start the **asynronous operation**. Beside that, it also block the current thread and I know that this situation is cause by the `allDone.waitOne()`.

Why the asynronous operation will not function and how to solve it?

Thank you for any help.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
            // Create a new HttpWebRequest object.
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            request.Method = "POST";

            // start the asynchronous operation
            request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);

            allDone.WaitOne();

        }
```

**Asynronous operation**:

```
private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;


            // End the operation
            Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

            string postData = "xxxxxxxxxxx";    
            // Convert the string into a byte array. 
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            // Write to the request stream.
            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
            postStream.Close();

            // Start the asynchronous operation to get the response
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
        }

        private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

            // End the operation
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
            string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
            tbtesting.Text = responseString.ToString();

            streamResponse.Close();
            streamRead.Close();

            response.Close();
            allDone.Set();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not the first to hit this (see [Is it possible to make synchronous network call on ui thread in wpf (windows phone)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15000274/694641)). If you do this then you deadlock the UI thread on Windows Phone.

The closest you're going to get is to use the async/await on your network calls. There are extension methods you can use to do this as part of the Microsoft.Bcl.Async package on NuGet.